# Python Selenium Multithreading Different Chrome Instances

Tags: python, selenium, python-multithreading

I am writing a code in python that opens 20 threads (each going through the same function), each thread opens a different selenium browser instance, each thread is been given a different url as parameter. So I have 20 selenium browsers opened, each on 20 different urls. This works perfect, until I add the `user-data-dir` selenium chrome option to every browser, in the thread function. I do this, because I want the selenium browsers opened on the same chrome icon on the taskbar (so it won't visually disturb the user). But the problem is : now I have 20 different selenium browsers opened, but all the thread commands are executed on just one (that single one browser navigates to all the 20 given urls, leaving the other 19, basically doing nothing). How can I solve this issue? Can I mix the selenium browsers in one chrome icon in a different way? This is very strange and I looked it up, for days, but nothing seems to solve my problem. I really want to solve this and if anyone knows what might be the problem, I would really appreciate some help. (I hope you understand the question.)

**EDIT** :
As https://stackoverflow.com/users/6393476/enriquebet mentioned in the comments, I tried using `ProcessPoolExecutor`, but that did no good, because my program also has a tkinter GUI app, therefore, by implementing this method, it freezes. So I figured I should use a basic multiprocessing program. It worked fine : the 20 drivers opened, with `user-data-dir` option, the GUI didn't freeze. But my program, also includes a `close_browser` button for each driver, that closes that specific driver. The problem is : I can't access the `driver` field, that is initiated after. I hope this code explains my issue (Note: I narrowed it down to just one driver, for avoiding complications) This is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import os
import time
import multiprocessing
import queue

from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

class Browser():
    pass

def close_browser():
    print("Closing browser...")
    browser.driver.close()




def start_browser_process(browser):
    print("Starting browser...")
    browser.driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

    while True:
        browser.driver.get(browser.url)
        time.sleep(5)

def start_browser():

    browser.process = multiprocessing.Process(target=start_browser_process, args=(browser,))
    browser.process.start()

if __name__=='__main__':

    browser = Browser()
    browser.url = 'https://facebook.com'


    root = tk.Tk()                    
    button_start_browser = tk.Button(root, command=start_browser, width=50, height=4, bg='red', text='Start Browser')
    button_start_browser.pack()

    button_close_browser = tk.Button(root, width=50, height=7, bg='red', command=close_browser, text='Close Browser')
    button_close_browser.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

So, first I create a Browser instance, that, for now, has just one field (an url) and initialize the Tkinter GUI App. Then, I press the `Start Browser` button, that opens for me a fresh selenium driver on `https://facebook.com`, that keeps reentering that url, every 5 seconds, also, I assign a new field to the Browser instance : `driver`. But then, when I press the `Close Browser` button, I want to access that `browser.driver` field, in order to close it, they give me this error : `AttributeError: 'Browser' object has no attribute 'driver'`. This means that I have to dynamically share the `driver` field between processes. I tried this with `Queue`, but that still didn't work as python doesn't let you pass queue objects as process arguments. How can I share variables between processes, in this case? Is there another way? I've been searching for 4 days now, but still didn't find the answer. Any answer is much appreciated. If you have questions regarding my issue, please announce me so I can edit the question.

Comment: Hi sucre, If you want to achieve this, you might need to perform this action with multi-processing, not multi-threading, take a look at the [concurrent.futures.PoolProcessExecutor](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor). For this you will need to execute the program on independent folders, each folder will need to have a copy of the user data you are trying to use.

Comment: It's a good idea. But there would be 1 issue : I am using tkinter and I am also passing tkinter objects as the process arguments, that gives me this error: `TypeError: can't pickle _tkinter.tkapp objects`. I tried to overcome this issue, but no good so far. And if you can help me, I would really appreciate it.